# LP-problem simplex with 3 variables

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I have this LP-problem which I need to solve using simplex calculations.

$$
\max Z = 12x_1 + 18x_2 + 10x_3
$$

when,

\begin{align}
2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 &= 50\\
-x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 0\\
-x_2 + \frac32x_3 & = 0\\
x_1 , x_2 , x_3 & > 0\\
\end{align}

How do I solve this? I'm quite confused about the constraint terms 2 & 3 which are equal to $0$. Do this even have possible solutions?

I get $Z = 300$ as a result of only one iteration. In my results $x_2$ will be entering the set of basic variables and replacing $s_2$ (s2 is slack variable for the constraint 2). But I think this is not right way to do it.

Starting table (pic1).
[image: pic1]

After first iteration results (pic2).
[image: pic2]

cj-zj values are all <0 which shows that we are "done" and we found the best alternative values.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! You write about one iteration, could you be more specific ? What do you call $s_2$ ? More generally, remember that you need to explain all the details when asking a question, because what may be clear for you is probably not for the others members. It is also required to show what you tired and where you failed. For instance you should here explain how you got $\max Z=300$ and why you are not sure.

Comment: You should provide more information about what you know regarding the simplex method, pivoting, etc.  In terms of math formatting, you can express the nonnegativity of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with a *weak inequality*, the $\LaTeX$ command for which is `\ge`.

Comment: @Tom-Tom now I edited the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189), especially the [MathJax code for writing simplex tableaux](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189).

Comment: Convert it into the dual.  That will be easier.

Comment: Note that in the first tableau 3rd row, you've made a careless mistake.  They should be shifted one column to the right except $s_3$.